# Excel - if and or function

Tags: excel, if-statement

The formula I'm trying to write is

```
CellA             CellB              CellC
Total Price       Order status       Delivery Status**
Null              Authorised    
Null              Authorised         Null
$100              Authorised         Authorised
```

if cell A = Null and cell C = Null or blank... then "ERROR"

How would I write the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming CellA is `A2` and CellC is `C2`, use this formula below

```
=IF(AND($A2="null",OR($C2="NULL",$C2="")),"ERROR","NoError")
```

if you have assigned variable name to each cell you can use `CellA` and `CellC` instead

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head...

```
=IF(A2 == "NULL", IF(OR(C2 == "NULL", C2 == ""), "ERROR", ""), "")
```